# what is the meaning of incx and incxy in blas?

Tags: blas

For the BLAS function sdot (n, x, incx, y, incy).

incx Specifies the increment for the elements of x.

What is the meaning of the parameter incx and incy?

Answer (score 0):

**sdot (n, x, incx, y, incy)** will return the value

***x(1)*y(1)+x(1+incx)*y(1+incy)+...+x(1+(n-1)*incx)*y(1+(n-1)*incy)***.

Please refer to the source code http://netlib.sandia.gov/blas/sdot.f for more information.

Comment: This is a blind link now. You can check http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d28/group__single__blas__level1_ga37a14d8598319955b711af0d64a6f56e.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose is the index increment for array x and y respectively.

```
index_x += incx
index_y += incy
```

They should be set to 1 in a standard case.

Answer (score 0):

Most often you store matrix in a single array. Say, if you want to multiply two different columns in one array. You have to set inc iny to refer to the correct elements.